# Jquery is not working with update panel while update panel is updated in asp.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Jquery is not working with update panel while update panel is updated in asp.NET

> Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="datepicker.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.datepicker" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dater").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <p>
            Pick a Date:
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="dater" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="dater_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you added ajaxtoolkit dll?? If not include it then in your page register it in this way **<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>**

Comment: have not added ajaxtoolkit.dll, using only basic ajax what Donnet is provided

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $(function () {
            $("#dater").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                $("#dater").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: working fine but i need to declare each an every control and i need a simplify which is applicable to all controls

Comment: yes, because you are using #ID, so you can call it using a common #CssClass for all date picker.
like `$(".daterclass").datepicker({changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });`
@RavisankarReddy

Comment: not only in date picker,same issue is coming in like tooltip messages, model views which ever controls are using jquery with update panel

Comment: that seems to be another Question. @RavisankarReddy

Answer (score 0):

not only in date picker,same issue is coming in like tooltip messages, model views which ever controls are using jquery with update panel